# Detaching events (C#)

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I have a small issue with properly detaching an EventHandler from an event.  Here is what I am working with:

In UIButton:

```
public void HookEvent(Action<object, EventArgs> action)
{
    Click += new EventHandler(action);
}
public void UnhookEvent(Action<object, EventArgs> action)
{
    Click -= new EventHandler(action);
}
```

In Main:

```
UIButton button = new Button();
button.HookEvent(OnButtonClick);
button.UnhookEvent(OnButtonClick);
```

The function that is being hooked:

```
public void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new Exception("Event Fired");
}
```

Using this if I comment out the Unhook line it goes through properly and the Exception is called.  However, if I leave it as shown above with the Unhook still there...the function still fires.  It doesn't unhook it.  If I add `Click = null;` below the `Click -= new EventHandler(action);` portion, then it works as expected. Doing so results in only allowing one function to be hooked at any given time though.

My only thought about what could be happening is that a new version of the function is being passed in since I am working with Action<>, but alas I even tried storing that function as a variable inside the button and when I went to remove it, an `if(storedAction == passedInAction)` results in a true.  I have no clue why this won't detach for me.

Thanks for your time fellas!

Comment: I would separate out the event subscription/unsubscription triggered by different event first..to me one button click calling both event handlers is confusing

Comment: Why do these functions (`HookEvent`, `UnhookEvent`) actually add over just letting would-be callers directly use the `+=` (**standard**) syntax for subscribing to events?

Comment: There's no scenario where `new Button()` is ever going to be correct.  You'll need to use the proper button control reference, not create a new one from scratch.

Comment: `new EventHandler(...)` is obsolete. You can just do += / -= directly on your action, assuming the signature matches the type of the event.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever There isn't really a plus to it, nor is there a real good reason.  It is something I figured I would try out and just play around with.

Comment: @Hans Passant I made a typo. It should be `UIButton button = new UIButton()` It's for a project that is also ported to the Xbox 360, hence why I am redoing the UI that I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're creating a new `EventHandler` in your hook and unhook methods. So you're not attaching `OnButtonClick`, but rather a wrapper around it.

Change your hook methods to:

```
public void HookEvent(EventHandler action) {
    Click += action;
}
public void UnhookEvent(EventHandler action) {
    Click -= action;
}
```

The rest of your code should still work, and your events should fire properly now.

Comment: Oh, I see.  That does make more sense.  Thanks!